Quarkus CORS Invalid Origin
I'm trying to grant our nonprod quarkus container CORS permission to run to http://localhost:8080. I get the feeling I have just a stupid mistake in the configuration, but I'm just not seeing it.  Maybe the curl commands I'm using to test the preflight are wrong?

quarkus-bom version 3.13.2

application.properties
%nonprod.quarkus.http.cors=true
%nonprod.quarkus.http.cors.access-control-allow-credentials=true
%nonprod.quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,POST,OPTIONS
%nonprod.quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:8080
%nonprod.quarkus.http.cors.headers=authorization,content-type,origin,accept,x-requested-with,access-control-allow-origin,access-control-request-method

curl command
curl "$API_SERVICE_HOST/api/portal/resources" -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -X OPTIONS -i

I get a HTTP 403 response with access-control-allow-methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS and can see in the quarkus log
{
    "@timestamp": "2024-09-09T14:40:45.482843394Z",
    "logger_name": "io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "message": "Invalid origin http://localhost:8080",
    "thread_name": "vert.x-eventloop-thread-1",
    "application": "msg-dex-api"
}

This is running keycloak authorization, but I have disabled the policy enforcer for OPTIONS method
%nonprod.quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.4.path=/api/*
%nonprod.quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.4.methods.1.method=OPTIONS
%nonprod.quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.4.methods.1.scopes=ANY
%nonprod.quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.4.methods.1.scopes-enforcement-mode=DISABLED
%nonprod.quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.4.enforcement-mode=DISABLED

And I don't include the Origin header I do get a 200 response, so the authorization server should not be interfering with the Options request.
curl "$API_SERVICE_HOST/api/portal/resources" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -X OPTIONS -i

Edit: curl -v headers (masked service address)
> OPTIONS /api/portal/resources HTTP/2
> Host: $API_SERVICE_HOST
> accept: */*
> origin: http://localhost:8080
> access-control-request-method: GET

Any thoughts on what I might have wrong here?
Additional Edit. I went looking through the https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/vertx-http/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/vertx/http/runtime/cors/CORSFilter.java
I've also tried different variants on what to put in origins based on what I found in the code in CORSFilter.java above

%nonprod.quarkus.http.cors.origins=*
%nonprod.quarkus.http.cors.origins=/.*/

With 1. the wildCardOrigin should have skipped past the !allowsOrigin checks entirely, but it still fails with a log state "Invalid origin http://localhost:8080" which I assume is line 153.
With 2. line 146 should have triggered true "|| isOriginAllowedByRegex(allowedOriginsRegex, origin)", but I actually see a log entry from line 147 and isSameOrigin which shouldn't happen. But here is the kicker, 147 is not logged if I send origin as * or http://localhost:8080, but is logged if I used https://www.google.com.
I also added https://www.google.com explicitly to the cors.origin and same result, the isSameOrigin line get logged, which with a match and lazy evaluation shouldn't have happened if I had this correct.
For some reason this makes me think there is a different CORSFilter used on http vs https schemes.
EDIT 3 (Adding additional logging)
{
    "@timestamp": "2024-09-10T14:10:23.790612802Z",
    "sequence": 198,
    "loggerClassName": "org.jboss.logging.Logger",
    "logger_name": "io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "message": "Same origin check has failed, the host values do not match. Request URI: https://msg-dex.myhost.com/api/portal/resources, origin: https://localhost:8080",
    "thread_name": "vert.x-eventloop-thread-1",
    "threadId": 23,
    "mdc": {},
    "ndc": "",
    "hostName": "99c748b91cb6",
    "processName": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/bin/java",
    "processId": 1,
    "sourceClassName": "io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter",
    "sourceFileName": "CORSFilter.java",
    "sourceMethodName": "isSameOriginSlowPath",
    "sourceLineNumber": 259,
    "sourceModuleName": null,
    "sourceModuleVersion": null,
    "application": "msg-dex-api"
}
{
    "@timestamp": "2024-09-10T14:10:23.79163831Z",
    "sequence": 199,
    "loggerClassName": "org.jboss.logging.Logger",
    "logger_name": "io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "message": "Invalid origin https://localhost:8080",
    "thread_name": "vert.x-eventloop-thread-1",
    "threadId": 23,
    "mdc": {},
    "ndc": "",
    "hostName": "99c748b91cb6",
    "processName": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/bin/java",
    "processId": 1,
    "sourceClassName": "io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter",
    "sourceFileName": "CORSFilter.java",
    "sourceMethodName": "handle",
    "sourceLineNumber": 153,
    "sourceModuleName": null,
    "sourceModuleVersion": null,
    "application": "msg-dex-api"
}
{
    "@timestamp": "2024-09-10T14:10:23.793910859Z",
    "sequence": 200,
    "loggerClassName": "org.jboss.logging.Logger",
    "logger_name": "io.quarkus.http.access-log",
    "level": "INFO",
    "message": "OPTIONS HTTP_1_1XXX.XXX.136.209 X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XXX.136.209\nX-Forwarded-Proto: https\nX-Forwarded-Port: 443\nX-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-66e0534f-506363231c716dc1753f91ba\norigin: https://localhost:8080\naccess-control-request-method: GET\nhost: msg-dex.myhost.com",
    "thread_name": "vert.x-eventloop-thread-1",
    "threadId": 23,
    "mdc": {},
    "ndc": "",
    "hostName": "99c748b91cb6",
    "processName": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/bin/java",
    "processId": 1,
    "sourceClassName": "io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.filters.accesslog.JBossLoggingAccessLogReceiver",
    "sourceFileName": "JBossLoggingAccessLogReceiver.java",
    "sourceMethodName": "logMessage",
    "sourceLineNumber": 44,
    "sourceModuleName": null,
    "sourceModuleVersion": null,
    "application": "msg-dex-api"
}


It all looks fine. My guess is that one of the following happens: 1) curl does not send this header at all since it is really a browser-env based header, it is not really relevant in the CLI mode, or, 2), there is some extra space around the http://localhost:8080, if yes, we'd need to fix it by trimming, or, 3) the nonprod profile is not activated. Please check these options and let us know

Try curl -v to see the request headers

I can see the nonprod profile activate as I'm using that to control the logging level, which is set as TRACE for debugging this.  As far as verbose on curl goes I do see the headers.  It auto added user-agent which I blanked out in subsequent calls.  Right now I'm trying to load the API and dump the CORSConfig.toString() to see if there is something missing.  I actually moved to /.*/ for origins and still no luck.

you might try with HTTPS for origin header there.  Maybe you're calling https url?  In that case it would fail to match scheme.... so -H "Origin: https://localhost:8080"  and %nonprod.quarkus.http.cors.origins=https://localhost:8080  That CORS routine checks the request.host which is itself.

if there's a reverse proxy there request.host might be the proxy.

Might be worth logging the HTTP headers at the server side, https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#configuring-http-access-logs

@browsermator you are correct, I changed http://localhost:8080 to https://localhost:8080 and it now acts in a similar where it logs the line at 147.
There is an AWS Load Balancer, but not a reverse proxy, unless that's embedded in the ECS system.  My understanding of adding CORS origins was that it would allow for scheme and port changes, or am i misunderstanding that.

@SergeyBeryozkin I added the headers logging along with line number, and updated the original posting this those log details.  I'm still working out how I could possibly get access to the CORFilter object in the API and output the toString() on it to see what is configured.

@AnthonyHeaney, perhaps it would be simplest at this point to set a breakpoint in the CORS filter, would you like to try it ?

so CORS rules in the browser would not allow wildcard origins or non-https non-simple credentialed requests.   (curl doesn't have those rules, but I think your backend is trying to use same logic)

@SergeyBeryozkin I found the issue.  Apparently at some point I set QUARKUS_HTTP_CORS_ORIGINS on the Task Definition.

Found my issue.
At some point in the past I had set
QUARKUS_HTTP_CORS_ORIGINS as part of the AWS Task Definition.

Environment variable trumps application.properties folks.

I removed that variable from the task and it is now work as I would expect.  So above is good working config, just don't override it and forget.  Doh!

Np, glad you have figured it out
